# How to solve InterFAX python library 400 error?

Tags: python, html, django, pdf, interfax

I've been working on a django project that needs to send faxes.
For sending faxes I am using [interfax python library](https://github.com/interfax/interfax-python).
To generate pdf from html, I am using xhtml2pdf.
I wrote like below, and it didn't work and threw an error.
I don't know what to do now.

Please help.

The code

```
# interfax authentication
interfax_password = config("INTERFAX_PASSWORD")
interfax_account = config("INTERFAX_ACCOUNT")
interfax = InterFAX(username=interfax_account, password=interfax_password)

f = File(interfax, pdf, mime_type="application/pdf")
fax_number = config("INTERFAX_DESTINATION")

# actually sending the data
fax = interfax.outbound.deliver(fax_number=fax_number, files=[f])
```

The error thrown

```
equests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url:https://rest.interfax.net/outbound/faxes?faxNumber=111111111
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: When I print the headers like this print(f.headers), I found that it was empty.

Comment: It is supposed to be Content-Type: application/pdf. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I just need to use the API directly.